# How to implement a next intent in alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

How do you implement an 'AMAZON.NextIntent' in an alexa skill. suppose I have 3 audios(a1, a2, a3) enqueued and a1 is playing. If the user sends the request using 'nextIntent', what should be the response so that alexa plays a2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexa SDK provides you ability to keep the state in session attributes. For Node.js it's `this.attributes`. You can read more about here in [Skill State Management](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#skill-state-management) section.

You can keep the current step in that attribute. Once your skill is started you can set the current step to "first" (or 1, or whatever).

Once the `AMAZON.NextIntent` is triggered, you check the state of the attribute and decide which audio file to play next.

Something like:

```
if (this.attribute['currentStep'] == 1) {
  playSound('a2')
}
```

You will be able to even persist those attributes in DynamoDB later on. [Check that section](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#persisting-skill-attributes-through-dynamodb).

In case you are not using Node.js for that, I'm pretty sure it is supported by other languages.